# Chrome extension fetch not refetching

Tags: google-chrome-extension, github-api-v3

i use an alarm for fetching github notifications using github v3 api, and noticing the fetch api are getting called timely, but are not getting the newest results, not sure what could be the problem?

```
 try{ 
    const count = await getNotifications(searchQueries);
    await chrome.storage.local.set({[dbName]: count})
    chrome.storage.local.get(dbName, showNotification);
 }catch(e) {
    console.log(e)
 }

 ...
 async function getNotifications(repo) {
   const headers = {
      'Authorization': `Bearer ${access_token}`,
      'Content-Type': 'application/json',
   }
   let response = await fetch(`https://api.github.com/notifications`, {headers});
   const notifications = await response.json();
   // alert(notifications.length)
   return notifications.length
 }
```

Comment: Try [fetch(), how do you make a non-cached request?](//stackoverflow.com/q/29246444)

Comment: @wOxxOm i checked the headers it's already in no-cache. But it's only working/updating to the new data if i inspect popup then refresh using cmd + r

Comment: @wOxxOm added code

Comment: The code looks fine. Try also `fetch(url, {cache: "no-store"})` and `"no-cache"`.

Comment: @wOxxOm ah the 'no-store' works. Thanks for the help 